# Why all my styles go wrong when I add figcaption?

Tags: html, css, width, gallery

I have a gallery on my site, but when I add figcaption it all goes wrong and each picture becomes central. What have I done incorrectly? I really can not imagine how to improve it.

```
  #image{
position: inherit;
width:300px;

-webkit-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
margin-top:10px; 

}

#image:hover{
position: inherit;
-webkit-transform:scale(3);
transform:scale(3);
margin: 0 auto; 
highslide: auto;
}

figure.img img {  
max-width: 300px;
height: auto;

}
figure.img figcaption {  
padding: 5px;
font: bold italic 90% Georgia,serif;
color: #17432e;
width: 300px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
.pictures {

margin: 100px auto;
width: 980px;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Then in body I have after all changes according to your advice

```
<div align="center">
    <figure class="img">

            <img id="image" src="pics/1.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>In the village</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="img">
            <img id="image" src="pics/2.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>August</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="img">
            <img id="image" src="pics/3.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>The bridge</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="img">
           <img id="image" src="pics/4.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>A cute house</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: Only one figcaption per figure is allowed

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want every picture to have a description? What tag to use?

Comment: Exchange you figure element with a div, and instead wrap each img/figcaption pair in a figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution.

---CSS Code--

```
figure img{
position: inherit;
width:300px;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
margin-top:10px; 
}

figure img:hover{
position: inherit;
-webkit-transform:scale(3);
transform:scale(3);
margin: 0 auto; 
highslide: auto;
}

figure> figcaption {  
padding: 5px;
font: bold italic 90% Georgia,serif;
color: #17432e;
width: 300px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

/----HTML Code -----/

```
<div align=center class="pictures">
  <figure class="img">
    <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>In the village</figcaption>

  </figure>
          <figure class="img">
            <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>In the village</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure class="img">
            <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>In the village</figcaption>

  </figure>

</div>
```

Here is a Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/musovipo/1/

Comment: Thank you! It helped very much. Sorry I do not have enough reputation to vote

Answer (score 0):

I've made the code more valid by removing the multiple identical id's
 and wrapping each img/figcaption pair with a figure element. To show the figures on same line, display: inline-block was added to the figure elements

**CSS**

```css
div.img img {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    position: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

    div.img img:hover {
        position: inherit;
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        transform: scale(3);
        margin: 0 auto;
        highslide: auto;
    }

div.img figcaption {
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold italic 90% Georgia,serif;
    color: #17432e;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

div.img figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="img">
    <div align=center class="pictures">
        <figure>
            <img src="pics/1.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>In the village</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="pics/2.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>August</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="pics/3.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>The bridge</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="pics/4.jpg" class="passe-partout">
            <figcaption>A cute house</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```